# Scrolling the Float

Tags: html, css

I am quite inexperienced when it comes to HTML/CSS, so please help me out.

I have the following layout

```
<style>
#main {background-color: red; width: 30%;}
#right_al{float: right;}
#to_scroll{overflow: scroll;}
</style>

<div id='main'>
    <div id='right_al'>
        CONTENT#foo
        <div id='to_scroll'>
        ZZZ<br />ZZZ<br />ZZZ<br />ZZZ<br />ZZZ<br />
        ZZZ<br />ZZZ<br />ZZZ<br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='div1'>CONTENT #1</div>
    <div id='div2'>CONTENT #2</div>
    <div id='div3'>CONTENT #3</div>
    <div id='div4'>CONTENT #4</div>
    <div id='div5'>CONTENT #5</div>
</div>
```

The `overflow: scroll` inside `#to_scroll` is to show what i want, it doesn't work. The `#right_al` crosses the parent boundary and clearing the float will increase the parent's size, which i don't want.

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/5ycnw/

What i want is

- div1 to div5 lies on the left inside the parent.
- the divs on the left decide the max height the parent div stretches to. The div floated to the right has a child `#to_scroll` which scrolls when its contents overflow the `#main`.

A solution i came up with involves fixing the height of the `right_al`, but the height of the parent `#main` is subject to the contents on the left divs and i want a CSS only solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could put a wrapper div around div to 5 and float it left.

Comment: @SvenBieder But i want the div1 to div5 to stretch the parent `#main`'s height which they won't i float them.

Comment: Have you got a jsFiddle?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs updated the question with the link.

Comment: Just want to make sure I get it right: you want to have the right element #right_al have the same height as #main? Using "float:right" already removed the element from the document flow so this solution will not work. Will try to show another solution without floating elements.

Comment: @SaschaM78 right. Any different solution?

Comment: I reread your initial question and I can't think of a solution without adding some height definition at some point. Imagine the following underlying problem: you have two "cells" (comparable to HTML tables) and both are part of the same row. Now the row's height needs to be calculated and therefore the height information of both cells is compared. If the right cell has overflow:scroll and a height, this height will be the minimum height of the row, without a defined height the row will stretch to fit the contents defined inside the right "cell".

Comment: More info from [W3C's overflow definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow-clipping): [Add scrollbars when] "an element's height exceeds an explicit height assigned to the containing block (i.e., the containing block's height is determined by the 'height' property, not by content height).". Following W3C's definition, you either have height+scrollbars or no height+no scrollbars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my above comment, the W3C specs will not allow scrolling containers when no height is given because the container's inner height will be used to define its total height. If using a bit of JS code would be an option, have a look at the following Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/kf3vD/

Here's my HTML structure I used in the demo:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="main-column">...</div>
<div id="side-bar">
  <div id="side-bar-header">
  Sidebar Header
  </div>
  <div id="side-bar-scroller">
      <ul>
          <li>Option 1</li>
          <li>Option 2</li>
          <li>Option 3</li>        
          <li>Option 4</li>
          <li>Option 5</li>
          <li>Option 6</li>                
          <li>Option 7</li>
          <li>Option 8</li>
          <li>Option 9</li>  
          <li>Option 10</li>
          <li>Option 11</li>
          <li>Option 12</li>               
      </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

​

When the document is completely loaded, height information of the left element (main content element) will be used to set the height of the scrolling element inside the side bar minus the height needed to display the title of the sidebar.

The essential part would be this short jQuery instruction:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mainHeight=$('#main-column').height();    
  var sidebarHeaderHeight=$('#side-bar-header').height();    
  $('#side-bar-scroller').css('height', mainHeight-sidebarHeaderHeight);
});​
```

I tested the code in Chrome only so you will definitely need a bit of fine-tuning there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put a wrapper  around the "content" divs, and then give that a float of left.

```
<div id="content-container">
    <div id='div1'>CONTENT #1</div>
    <div id='div2'>CONTENT #2</div>
    <div id='div3'>CONTENT #3</div>
    <div id='div4'>CONTENT #4</div>
    <div id='div5'>CONTENT #5</div>
</div>


// CSS

#content-container { float:left; }
#main { height:auto; }
```

Before you close the main tag, do a CSS clear. Add this:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: But then the parent `#main` gets no height

Comment: Edited the code. Add a clear:both. Here's an explanation on that: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Comment: Now the `#main` expands to fit both the container and the div i want to scroll, same as my original code+clearing thr right float. btw changed `left_al` to `right_al` in the question as to avoid confusion.